# Solana stake pool installation issue

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana

While using cargo install spl-stake-pool-cli

I am getting issues with the last step. Please check the attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

so for now you'll need to be using strictly version 1.6.11 of the SDK and it should work. These dependency changes will also be added to the next release so you can expect it moving forward.